# What does ''as'' mean in sentences below?

Tags: meaning

> A more complex issue is calculating the amount of resources required in light of the stochastic failure rates of hardware resources in the system **as coupled with** varying user requests for VMs.

> These differences between rice and Arabidopsis in their storage reserves for late pollen might explain why genes related to the metabolism of major carbohydrates are enriched in rice divergent genes, **as coupled with** late pollen development.

I couldn't understand what ''as'' mean in these sentence. Can you please explain what it means.Is it used as an adverb to describe how it happens? Would the meaning change if I didn't use ''as''? Or can I say ''... in the way coupled with...''?

Comment: I think, although by no means sure, that as coupled with means in conjunction with. Neither sentence is very clear, as least to me.

Comment: Yes, these sentences are not well written. In the first sentence, *as coupled with* could be replaced by *as well as* to make it clearer.